# How to ignore rule for a href using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have simple rule form all `<a>`:

```
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:active {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

But I don't want this to apply for `<img>` inside `<a>`:

```
<a href="link">
     <img class="myClass" src="smile.png" alt="this is image link example">
</a>
```

How can I ignore this?

Comment: Why you don't try using a class to set styles for link and when you've a img don't use class

Comment: Well I would change structure here, but if you really want to ignore rule with this structure, wrap it all in span with some class and style it as you want

Comment: there are no parent selector so I think you can apply any of the above two said.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add another set of classes after the first, targeting a img, a img:hover, etc. However, an img element doesn't support text-decoration. What is it your trying to avoid with the image?

Answer (score 0):

Put your href inside of a div and assign a class to that div; you can then style the class followed by a:

```
<div class="stylin">
   <a href="link">
       <img class="myClass" src="smile.png" alt="this is image link example">
   </a>
</div>
```

And then in the stylesheet.

```
.stylin a:link {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to look and see if an img has a link as a parent (parent selector) to then change the link element based on that.  You would need Javascript or JQuery to do that or you can just add a 'link-img' class to any link elements containing an image and set it's CSS properties accordingly.

HTML:

```
<a href="#">Link 1</a>
<a href="#">Link 2</a>
<a href="#">Link 3</a>
<a class="link-img" href="#">
    <img src="smile.png"/>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.link-img {
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a class to the `<a>` tag.

For example

```
<a href="link" class="image">
 <img class="myClass" src="smile.png" alt="this is image link example">
</a>
```

and then with css:

```
a.image{

}
```

In this example you would have to specifically set rules to counter the previously set rules for all `<a>` tags

Another approach would be to use the extra class in conjunction with the `:not` selector

```
a:link:not(.image) {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited:not(.image) {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover:not(.image) {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:active:not(.image) {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
a:link .myClass,
a:visited .myClass,
a:hover .myClass,
a:focus .myClass,
a:active .myClass {
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Not working. Still I have "underline" after mouse on img.